# Retrieve data with 2 decimal place

Tags: java

I have a problem in retriving data with two decimal places from the database.
I was using resultset.getDouble() method. But this gives me only 1 decimal places on the result. I tried using the DecimalFormat to convert to 2 decimal. When I run my code, I'm getting the error "String cannot convert to double" from DisplayFood.java

DisplayFood.java

```
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultset = null;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

String query = "SELECT * FROM food";
statement = connection.createStatement();

resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);

while(resultset.next())
{
     FoodRecord foodmenu = new FoodRecord();
     foodmenu.setItemName(resultset.getString("itemName"));

     foodmenu.setPrice(df.format(resultset.getDouble("price")));
     foodmenu.setRestaurant(resultset.getString("restaurant"));

     food.add(foodmenu);
}
```

FoodRecord.java

```
public class FoodRecord {
    private String itemName;
    private double price;
    private String restaurant;

    public FoodRecord() {
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getRestaurant() {
        return restaurant;
    }

    public void setRestaurant(String restaurant) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is all wrong. Money in a database should be stored as DECIMAL, not DOUBLE. There's no such thing as a `double` with two decimal places. You should use `BigDecimal` in the Java code.

Comment: @Lue Fang - want to give some credit to the users that are helping you. That's how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

> I was using resultset.getDouble() method. But this gives me only 1
>   decimal places on the result

The `getDouble()` method returns the value number as a double is represented in java.

The `getDouble()` javadoc :

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of
>   this ResultSet object as a double in the Java programming language.

It means if your number value is `10.5`, the double will have as value `10.5` and not `10.50`.

> I tried using the DecimalFormat to convert to 2 decimal

`DecimalFormat.format(double number)` formats a double as a `String` with a specific format. 
The format specified is here in your code :

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

So, yes you cannot assign a `Double` to a `String` as these are not compatible types.
To solve your problem, you have to store the result of `DecimalFormat.format(double number)` in a `String`.

But it is indeed not not consistent with the `FoodRecord` class where `price` is a `double` field :     `private double price;`

Changing `price` from `double` to `String` in the class is not necessarily the best way for two reasons :

- the visual representation of a data should not change the data value.
  If the decimal is on 4 floating value (for example : `10.5445`), formatting it to `10.54` and storing the information in the class only as a `String` field truncates the data value. If you store again the value in your database, it changes the initial value while the object was not modified by the client.
- you could not any longer have a simple `setPrice()` method with a double (so in a natural way) as you should perform some computations in the `setPrice()` method to change the `double` to a `String`.

To solve your problem, you could introduce a new method that returns the formatted price :

```
public String getFormatedPrice(){
  return df.format(resultset.getDouble("price"));
}
```

If `getFormatedPrice()` is frequently invoked, the result could be cached instead of invoking `df.format()`.

Answer (score 0):

You get this Error bacause You are trying to set a String value in a double Field. 
Use `resultset.getDouble("price")` to read the items Price from resultset.

To print the Price with two decimal Places you can use your formatter with System.out.println like `df.format(foodMenu.getPrice())`.